# Laravel - Change URL parameters using GET

Tags: laravel

I have RESTful API built on Laravel.

Now I'm passing parameter like
http://www.compute.com/api/GetAPI/1/1

but I want to pass parameter like
http://www.compute.com/api/GetAPI?id=1&page_no=1

Is there a way to change Laravel routes/functions to support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use link_to_route() and link_to_action() methods too.
([source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/generating-a-route-with-a-query-string-parameter))

link_to_route take three parameters (name, title and parameters). you can use it like following:

```
link_to_route('api.GetAPI', 'get api', [ 
  'page_no' => $page_no,
  'id' => $id
]);
```

If you want to use an action, link_to_action() is very similar but it uses action name instead of route.

```
link_to_action('ApiController@getApi', 'get api', [ 
  'page_no' => $page_no,
  'id' => $id
]);
```

[href text](http://domain.com/api/GetAPI?page_no=page_no_you_passed&id=id_you_passed)

with these methods anything after the expected number of parameters is exceeded, the remaining arguments will be added as a query string.

Or you can use traditional concatination like following:
create a route in routes.php

```
Route::get('api/GetAPI', [
  'as' => 'get_api', 'uses' => 'ApiController@getApi'
]);
```

while using it append query string like this. you can use route method to get url for required method in controller. I prefer action method.

```
$url = action('ApiController@getApi'). '?id=1&page_no=1';
```

and in your controller access these variables by following methods.

```
public function getApi(Request $request) {
  if($request->has('page_no')){
    $page = $request->input('page_no');
  }

   // ...your stuff
}
```

Or by Input Class

```
public function getApi() {
  if(Input::get('page_no')){
    $page = Input::get('page_no');
  }

   // ...your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use those parameters, then in your controllers you can get their values using the `Request` object.

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    if($request->has('page_no')){
        $page = $request->input('page_no');
    }

    // ...
}
```